# Size Constrained Integer Partitions of a Given Number

Tags: python, generator, combinations, partitioning

As a smaller part of a programming challenge, I am writing a function in Python that takes two parameters, a given number and a size constraint. The function yields a generator that produces the integer partitions of the given number up to the size constraint. I have a working solution that is derived from the rule_asc algorithm:

```
def rule_asc(n):
    a = [0 for i in range(n + 1)]
    k = 1
    a[1] = n
    while k != 0:
        x = a[k - 1] + 1
        y = a[k] - 1
        k -= 1
        while x <= y:
            a[k] = x
            y -= x
            k += 1
        a[k] = x + y
        yield a[:k + 1]
```

So to implement the size constraint there is a simple addition to the first nested while loop:

```
def generate_subproblems(total_nodes, colors):
    all_partitions = [0 for i in range(colors)]
    k = 1
    all_partitions[0] = 0
    all_partitions[1] = total_nodes
    while k != 0:
        x = all_partitions[k - 1] + 1
        y = all_partitions[k] - 1
        k -= 1
        while x <= y and k < colors - 1:
            all_partitions[k] = x
            y -= x
            k += 1
        all_partitions[k] = x + y

        current_partition = all_partitions[:k + 1]
        yield current_partition
```

This yields all the partitions of `total_nodes` with length `<= colors`.

For example, the code:

```
for _ in generate_subproblems(6, 3):
    print(_)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 1, 4]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 5]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 4]
[3, 3]
[6]
```

Which are all the integer partitions of the number 6 of size less than or equal to 3.

The problem I am facing is that the algorithm is too slow for larger values, by larger I mean anything over 100. The place where I got the first algorithm (https://jeromekelleher.net/category/combinatorics.html) to begin with lists a different, quicker implementation:

```
def accel_asc(n):
    a = [0 for i in range(n + 1)]
    k = 1
    y = n - 1
    while k != 0:
        x = a[k - 1] + 1
        k -= 1
        while 2 * x <= y:
            a[k] = x
            y -= x
            k += 1
        l = k + 1
        while x <= y:
            a[k] = x
            a[l] = y
            yield a[:k + 2]
            x += 1
            y -= 1
        a[k] = x + y
        y = x + y - 1
        yield a[:k + 1]
```

However I am unable to wrap my head around this implementation so as to introduce the size constraint. How can I modify the accel_asc function to just yield the partitions less than a specified size?

Comment: Considering you already have working code. It seems to me this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Comment: If its performance you are going for, you can try to write in a compiled language like c++. You could be satisfied with the first solution itself if its written in c++.

Answer (score 0):

A very late answer, but I believe this is what you are asking for. You need to add the "colors" constraint to both inner loops.

```py
def generate_subproblems_2(total_nodes, colors):

    n = total_nodes

    a = [0 for i in range(colors)]
    k = 1
    y = n - 1

    while k != 0:
        x = a[k - 1] + 1
        k -= 1

        while 2 * x <= y and k < colors - 1:
            a[k] = x
            y -= x
            k += 1

        l = k + 1

        while x <= y and k < colors - 1:

            a[k] = x
            a[l] = y

            yield a[:k + 2]

            x += 1
            y -= 1

        a[k] = x + y
        y = x + y - 1

        yield a[:k + 1]
```